# What does this line AppleScript means?

Tags: applescript

I've 1 line AppleScript, I wanna know what does this AppleScript do?

```
do shell script "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --enable-speech-input"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess, having never used AppleScript before, that this will launch Google Chrome passing the parameter `--enable-speech-input`

According to [this](http://googlemonthly.com/google-chrome-web-browser/how-to-enable-voice-search-in-google-chrome.html), it is used to enable Google Voice Search in Chrome.

Hope that helps.